# Generating android manifest and declaring activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Here's another newbie question about android programming.
How is the androidmanifest.xml file generated, and what determines if an activity will be registered (declared) in it? My androidstudio ignores one of my activities (doesn't register it in the generated manifest) and I'd like to understand why and what to look for....
Thanks and have a nice day,
J

Comment: You have to declare and edit the manifest as the app builds.  It's one of those things that's both annoying but also helpful at times.

Comment: But why other activities get registered and this one doesn't? Maybe it indicates that something's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The default one is registered when you create the project, but that's the wizard doing that.  You can delete it and put your own if you want/needed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 things you have to do when you manually create an activity:

1. Create a class that extends from `Activity` (or from another class which IS-A Activity)
2. Add your activity to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

I don't really understand what you mean by "ignores activity".

You can find more information about AndroidManifest [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Hope this help!

Comment: When i say that it "ignores", I mean that out of 3 activities in my project, only 2 were automatically added to the manifest file (I didn't add them, they were " builded" into the manifest) and one activity wasn't.

Comment: Ok I get your idea. If you are creating an activity using wizard of the IDE (android studio or eclipse) then your new activity will not be "ignored" :)

If you are creating an activity manually (which is create new class and extends Activity) then you have to put it to your Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

the mainfiest is created when you create your project.

you will need to declare all of your activities in the manifest like so

```
     <activity
        android:name="ExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

within the manifest is where you would also declare what permissions the app needs like connecting to the internet etc.

Answer (score 0):

Android Run Time just use this manifest.xml file for checking the android component created by you,which are using in Application,before creating the instance of your customize component which extends Activity,Service,Broadcast Reciever,Content Provoider.